# Why is not my facebook bot replaying all who are sending message to my page?

Tags: php

My facebook bot replying only page author but without page author it is not replying answer other who are sending message to my page.I could not find any solution for this.My code is given below :

```
  <?php  
      $challenge = $_REQUEST['hub_challenge'];
      $verify_token = $_REQUEST['hub_verify_token'];

      $accessToken = "mytokem is here";

      // Set this Verify Token Value on your Facebook App 
      if ($verify_token === 'Verifytoken') {
         echo $challenge;
      }
     $input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
     // Get the Senders Graph ID
     $sender = $input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['sender']['id'];
     // Get the returned message
     $message = $input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['message']['text'];
     echo $message;
     //API Url and Access Token, generate this token value on your Facebook App Page
     $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?         access_token='.$accessToken;
     //Initiate cURL.
      $ch = curl_init($url);
     //The JSON data.
     $jsonData = '{
        "recipient":{
             "id":"' . $sender . '"
         }, 
         "message":{
             "text":"hello user"
         }
      }';
      //Tell cURL that we want to send a POST request.
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
      //Attach our encoded JSON string to the POST fields.
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonData);
      //Set the content type to application/json
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:           application/json'));
      //Execute the request but first check if the message is not empty.
      if(!empty($input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['message'])){
          $result = curl_exec($ch);
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your fb bot app in testing mode?
Your fb app Approved by facebook.
if app in testing then only admin or tester are able to use bot.

You have to go through a review process before your bot is open to the world, ready to chat with anyone.

Comment: how will I  go for review process to do this ?

Comment: If your bot is ready,you send review request to fb as  follow Step #7 in this lnkhttps://blog.hartleybrody.com/fb-messenger-bot/

Comment: you can read from fb docs https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/app-review